# Google Apps Script: How to expand columns based on unique column members?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to transpose the 4 unique dates into 4 columns in another sheet. The other sheet only has two columns and will need to add 2 more columns to accommodate the transpose using `insertColumns`.

How can I achieve this using only Google Apps Script wherein the scripts checks whether the sheet has enough columns and inserts them accordingly if not?

[image]

```
function unique() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lrow-1, 1).getValues();
  var unique = [...new Set(range)]

  Logger.log(unique.length);  // Not returning unique length - 7.0

}
```

Comment: I would get the data into a 2d array and splice in the new columns. Then clear the old range and use setValues() to insert the new data with new columns

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my question with some code, where I am getting the 2d array, but the date values cannot be converted to a unique array. My best bet is to get the values in the `DATEVALUE` format and remove duplicates accordingly. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Yeah you need to convert them to values.  I have a solution below.  You still need to add headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Unique Dates

```
function unique() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().map(d => d.valueOf());
  var uvs = [...new Set(vs)].map(v => new Date(v));
  if(sh.getMaxColumns() < uvs.length) {
    sh.insertColumnsAfter(sh.getLastColumn(), uvs.length - sh.getLastColumn() - 1)
  }
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(2,1,1,uvs.length).setValues([uvs]);
}
```

Before:

| Date |
| --- |
| 1/1/2022 |
| 1/2/2022 |
| 1/3/2022 |
| 1/4/2022 |
| 1/4/2022 |
| 1/4/2022 |
| 1/4/2022 |
| 1/4/2022 |
| 1/4/2022 |
| 1/4/2022 |

After:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 1/2/2022 | 1/3/2022 | 1/4/2022 |